# Java library that enables ${var} substitution

Tags: java, text

Does anyone know of a Java library that provides support for the ${var} style substitution in text files?

Comment: It's basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368802/how-to-create-dynamic-template-string/2368810#2368810

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic Template String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368802/how-to-create-dynamic-template-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Velocity ( http://velocity.apache.org ), FreeMarker ( https://freemarker.apache.org/ )

Answer (score 11):

Use `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor`

Example 1 (the simplest example is to use this class to replace Java System properties):

```
  StrSubstitutor.replaceSystemProperties(
    "You are running with java.version = ${java.version} and os.name = ${os.name}.");
```

Example 2:

```
   Map valuesMap = HashMap();
   valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
   valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
   String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";
   StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
   String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

yielding:

```
   The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

- [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html)
- [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

Comment: This works! StrSubstitutor is now deprecated, use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass up [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) it is probably the cleanest separation of data and template concerns and is very robust.

Comment: This one is actually very good, it is backed up by Terence Parr, who is also the author of ANTLR.

Answer (score 3):

Java's [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/MessageFormat.html) class allows for semi-advanced text substitution, with localization and formatting support for numbers, dates and time. And for pluralization, you may even use java.text.ChoiceFormat with MessageFormat.
It may be enough for all your text-substitution needs.

If not, you can take a look at Apache Velocity (http://velocity.apache.org/) or Freemarker(http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Good to know that Sun has their own built-in tool for this.  It works well if you don't want to include any other libraries.  It is also available in Java 1.4 and 5.