# Replacing variable in String

Tags: java, string

I have a string which has the below content

```
String msg = "The variables &CHAG_EF and &CHAG_DNE_DTE can be embedded"

String test1 = "22/10/2010 00:10:12"
String test2 = "25/10/2010 00:01:12"
```

I need to search the string variable msg for the string `"&CHAG_EF"` and if it exists replace with the value of `test1` and also search the string variable msg for the string `"&CHAG_DNE_DTE"` and if it exists replace with the value of `test2`.

How can i replace them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So simple!

```
String msg2 = msg.replace("&CHAG_EF", test1).replace("&CHAG_DNE_DTE", test2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Strings can't be modified in Java so you'll need to create new versions with the correct modified values. There are two ways to approach this problem:

1. Dynamically hard-code all the replacements like other posters have suggested. This isn't scalable with large strings or a large number of replacements; or
2. You loop through the String looking for potential variables. If they're in your replacement `Map` then replace them. This is very similar to [How to create dynamic Template String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368802/how-to-create-dynamic-template-string/2368810#2368810).

The code for (2) looks something like this:

```
public static String replaceAll(String text, Map<String, String> params) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&(\\w+)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
  boolean result = m.find();
  if (result) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do {
      String replacement = params.get(m.group(1));
      if (replacement == null) {
        replacement = m.group();
      }
      m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
      result = m.find();
    } while (result);
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
  }
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are immutable, so any of the "manipulation" methods return a new string rather than modifying the existing one. One nice thing about this is that you can chain operations in many cases, like this:

```
String result = msg.replace("&CHAG_EF", test1)
                   .replace("&CHAG_DNE_DTE", test2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 msg = msg.replace("&CHAG_EF", test1).replace("&CHAG_DNE_DTE", test2);
```